# The limit of the measure of a sequence of sets is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $(X, M, μ)$ be a measure space. I am looking for a sequence of measurable sets such that the limit of the measure of a sequence of sets is zero, but the measure of the limit superior of the sets is not zero. I think the following classic construction will serve my purpose.(I copied it from Wikipedia) Let's define:

$$ E_n=  \left[\frac {j}{2^k}, \frac {j+1}{2^k} \right]$$

where,

$$ k=\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$$

$$ j=n-2^k$$

Intuitively I can feel that the limit superior of the sequence
$\{E_n\}$ is the closed inteval $[0,1]$. However, I am struggling to prove it. Could you please help me? Also, my guess might be incorrect. Thanks so much. Have a great day.

Comment: the limit superior of a sequence of sets is the set composed by the points that appear infinitely often in that sequence, then the limit superior is [0,1] if and only if for each $x\in[0,1]$ there is a subsequence such that $x$ belong to every set of that subsequence

Comment: we will have that

$$
E_n=\left[\frac{n}{2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}}-1,\frac{n+1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}}-1\right]=2^{\{\log_2 n\}}\left[1,1+\frac1{n}\right]-1
$$

where $\{x\}$ is the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$. Then the Lebesgue measure of each $E_n$ is $\lambda(E_n)=2^{\{\log_2 n\}}/n$. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please allow me to check the computations. Thank you so so so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. From your hints, it is also seen that for special type of ie n = 2^k, our interval is in fact [0, 1/n] which clearly tells us for any x in  [0, 1] we must have an interval containing. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you deleted your answer? I am trying to accept your answer. However, I don't find the answer.

Comment: I rewrote my answer as a comment because I wasn't sure that what I had written give you a way to solve the question. Note that you need more than one interval containing a point... you need infinitely $E_n$ that contain a point to know that this point is in the limit superior of the sequence

Comment: Yes, I understood that part. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Could you please clarify a little more? Now, I feel like I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in \Bbb N$ let  $D(n)$ be a  finite family of Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ such that $\cup D(n)=[0,1]$ and such that $0<\min \{\mu(d):d\in D(n)\}\le\max \{\mu(d):d\in D(n)\}\le 2^{-n},$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

For example $D(n) =\{[\,k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}\,]: 0\le k<2^{-n};\, k\in \Bbb Z\}.$

Now $D(n)$ has at least $2^n$ members so $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}D(n)$ is countably infinite. Let $f:\Bbb N\to \cup_{n\in \Bbb N}D(n)$ be any bijection.

Given $\epsilon>0,$ take $m\in \Bbb N$ with $2^{-m}<\epsilon$ and let $n_{\epsilon}=\max f^{-1}(\,\cup_{j=1}^m D(j)\,).$ Now if $n>n_{\epsilon}$ then $f(n)\in D(k)$ for some $k>m,$ so $n>n_{\epsilon}\implies \mu(f(n))<2^{-m}<\epsilon.$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(f(n))=0.$

Given $x\in [0,1]$ and $n\in \Bbb N:$ For $n\ge m\in \Bbb N$ choose $g(m)\in \Bbb N$ such that $f(m)\in D(g(m)).$ Let $n'=\max \{g(m):m\le n\}.$

Let $r=\frac {1}{2}\min \{ \mu(d):d\in \cup_{j\le n'}D(j)\}.$

Let $n''\ge n+n'$ where $n''$ is large enough that $\max \{\mu(d):d\in D(n'')\}\le r.$ Now  for some $n_0$ we have $x\in f(n_0)\in D(n'')$...(because $\cup D(n'')=[0,1]$ ). Observe that $k\le n \implies \mu(f(k))\ge 2r,$ but $\mu(f(n_0)\le r. So $n_0>n.$

So  $\forall n\in \Bbb N\,\exists n_0>n\,(x\in f(n_0).$

Therefore $\{j\in \Bbb N: x\in f(j)\}$ is infinite so $x\in \lim \sup_nf(n).$